# Discord.js random role reactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that sends an embed and reacts with an emoji and when a member clicks the emoji it gives them a random role. any idea on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Please post a code you tried so far. SO is not code writing service, the community can only help if you post a question with detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {Client, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

client.on('messageCreate', async ({author, channel, guild, member}) => {
  // don't do anything if it's a bot
  if (author.bot) return

  // don't do it if it's a DM
  if (!guild) return

  // replace these with whatever you want
  const embed = new MessageEmbed({title: 'some embed'})
  const emoji = ''

  const roles = guild.roles.cache.filter(role =>
    // you can't add the @everyone role
    role.name !== '@everyone' &&
    // or managed roles
    !role.managed &&
    // or roles that the bot isn't above
    guild.me.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(role) > 0
  )

  try {
    if (!roles.size) return await channel.send('There are no roles that I can add!')

    const message = await message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    await message.react(emoji)
    await message.awaitReactions({
      // only for await for the  emoji from the message author
      filter: (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === emoji && user.id === author.id,
      // stop after 1 reaction
      max: 1
    })
    await member.roles.add(roles.random())
  } catch (error) {
    // log all errors
    console.error(error)
  }
})

client.login('your token')
```

Note: Your bot must have the `MANAGE_ROLES` permission to be able to add a role to a guild member.